# How to check data from two worksheets in Excel 2016?

Tags: excel, vlookup, excel-match

I have raw data from an Excel Query that gives me details for Account Numbers(Field 2). I also have a list of Account Numbers that I want to EXCLUDE from the raw data.

Initially, I thought I could exclude them in SQL with the NOT IN condition. But I was then told that there are about 20,000 Accounts to Exclude.

So, I thought, I could export the raw data to Excel in one Worksheet and Add the Account Numbers to exclude in another worksheet and then have Excel check for those Account Numbers and give a Comment.

**Worksheet 1 (Raw Data):**

```
---------------------------------
|Field 1|Field 2|Field 3|Field 4|
---------------------------------
|   1234| A1234B|    XYZ| 258.00|
---------------------------------
|   2678| B1234C|    ABC| 457.25|
---------------------------------
|   5465| C1234D|    DEF| 652.47|
---------------------------------
|   4587| D1234E|    GHI| 458.36|
---------------------------------
|   3589| E1234F|    JKL| 685.47|
---------------------------------
```

**Worksheet 2 (Accounts to Exclude):**

```
---------
|Field 2|
---------
| A1234B|
---------
| J1234L|
---------
| K1234Z|
---------
| D1234E|
---------
| L1234M|
---------
```

**Intended Result:**

```
------------------------------------------
|Field 1|Field 2|Field 3|Field 4|Result  |
------------------------------------------
|   1234| A1234B|    XYZ| 258.00|Excluded|
------------------------------------------
|   2678| B1234C|    ABC| 457.25|        |
------------------------------------------
|   5465| C1234D|    DEF| 652.47|        |
------------------------------------------
|   4587| D1234E|    GHI| 458.36|Excluded|
------------------------------------------
|   3589| E1234F|    JKL| 685.47|        |
------------------------------------------
```

Initially, I started by sorting the Account Numbers on both worksheets and then ran the formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,ExcludedAccounts,2,FALSE), "Excluded")
```

But then I realised, I am only looking for exact match for each cell. That won't be right.

**Question:**
What is the Formula to check two columns from different worksheets for similarities across the whole column?

Once I have the flag "Excluded" in another column then I can highlight cell with Conditional Formatting and then segregate those accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough rep to post a comment.  The OPs formula is fine, if the "ExcludedRange" covers **two columns** (as he is returning what is in the second column) with the second column containing only blank spaces.

I'm not sure though what is meant by the below - could you please explain what the similarities are...

> ...different worksheets for **similarities** across the whole column

This is another way of doing it with a single column for the excludedrange

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,ExcludedAccounts,1,0)),"Excluded","")
```

Comment: Be careful with VLOOKUP as it requires you to sort the data, which is an extra step you'd have to be sure you do. I personally don't use it myself, but I agree that @Kwakkers answer should work as well.

Comment: Howdy, sorting is only required when you are looking for an approximate (parameter 4 = TRUE) match.  My example is an exact match (parameter 4 = FALSE), so sorting is irrelevant. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think the formula you're actually looking for is

`=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,ExcludedAccounts,0)),"Excluded","")`

When I used your formula, all I received were "Excluded" answers for everything because it was returning an error (this was possibly caused by missing information in your question, but I don't know). EDIT: As stated in the other answer that was submitted, yes, the original formula was looking to return a value from a second column, which would mean that *ExcludedAccounts* covers a minimum of two columns, not the assumed one.

There are several ways you can handle your request. However, what my above formula does is look for an **exact** match of the value in `B2` against those values in the *ExcludedAccounts* named range (which I assumed is `Sheet2!A2:A6`). If `MATCH` finds one, a number will be returned (this number represents the row within *ExcludedAccounts* where the value from `B2` was found). By wrapping this in the `ISNUMBER` function and placing it inside an `IF` statement, we're asking Excel to give us the result of "Excluded" if the excluded account is found on the list, and a result of "" if it isn't on the *ExcludedAccounts* list.